# If select returns nothing then

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write select as:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1 a 
  WHERE a.d > (
    SELECT b.d FROM table2 b 
     WHERE a.id = b.id and a.Something = 1
  )
```

BUT if the nested select does not returns any value so SELECT does not returns anything either.

Is possible to write something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1 a WHERE a.d > 
(SELECT * FROM 
   IF EXISTS (
        SELECT b.d FROM table2 b WHERE a.id = b.id and a.Something = 1
   )
      SELECT b.d FROM table2 b WHERE a.id = b.id and a.Something = 1 )
   ELSE 
      SELECT '0'
)
```

Comment: Eh, `...a.d > ANY(SELECT...` or `...a.d > ALL(SELECT...` depending on what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE`

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 a 
WHERE a.d > COALESCE((SELECT b.d FROM table2 b WHERE a.id = b.id and a.Something = 1), '0')
```

> COALESCE
>
> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current
>   value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to
>   NULL.

See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190349.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more info.

Comment: Thank you. It works for me. But I tried CASE WHEN ... THEN ... It works too but your solution is faster. Thanks